# Loop awk math over all columns

Tags: math, awk

I have an awk script where I do some arithmetic to a file and want to loop the equation over all the columns in the file. When I apply the equation to just a singular column, it works, but my attempt to loop it fails and outputs the results incorrectly and all into the same column (which I would like to keep them in their separate columns). My singular column equation that works is:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
}
{

    if(NR == 1) {
           blank = $1
       }
    if(NR == 2) {
           zero = $1
       }
    base = zero - blank;

    if(NR > 3) {

    print (($1 - blank)/base) >> "data.txt"

    }


}
END {
}
```

Input:

```
10
20
30
40
50
```

Output

```
2
3
4
```

My attempt to do over multiple columns:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
}
{
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    if(NR == 1) {
           blank = $i
       }
    if(NR == 2) {
           zero = $i
       }
    base = zero - blank;

    if(NR > 3) {

       print (($i - blank)/base) >> "data.txt"

    }
    }

}
END {
}
```

Input:

```
10 60
20 70
30 80
40 90
50 100
```

Output:

```
-2
3
-1
4
```

Expected Output:

```
2 2
3 3
4 4
```

Also, with the attempt to loop over all columns I wasn't able to just output the results to override the original file as I would like since it would add more and more and create an infinite loop. Above I had to output to a different file but I would like to just override the original file with the results.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: oh, I'll edit the looped one with expected output. The singular column one is the correct expected output.

Comment: The first awk program does not produce that output.

Comment: I'm sorry, I copy pasted the wrong tests i did on it from the wrong folder. Have tried it like 20 different ways and got confused. It should be correct now.

Comment: script, problem description and sample output don't match?  Are you ignoring first two rows of all columns except the first (60 and 70 in your test case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your test case output is wrong, this might be what you're looking for (the same formula for each column):

```
$ awk 'NR==1{split($0,b);next} 
       NR==2{split($0,z);next} 
            {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s", ($i-b[i])/(z[i]-b[i]) OFS; 
             print ""}' file
```

will give you

```
2 2
3 3
4 4
```

Comment: thanks! my expected output was wrong. gosh i feel like i asked this question in such a mess but this really helped! glenn's answer also helped me understand this better as well. thanks to you both!

Comment: i upvoted it but i don't have enough rep for it to be shown sadly :(

Answer (score 0):

```
seq 10 10 100 | pr -2Ts" " | awk '
    NR == 1 {blank = $1} 
    NR == 2 {zero = $1} 
    NR >= 3 {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
            $i = ($i - blank) / (zero - blank)
        print 
    }
'
```

```
2 7
3 8
4 9
```

You need to take care which field you need to capture in those oddly-named variables.

Comment: You are not using 60 and 70, second column first two values?

Comment: Well, I did ask for the expected output, so this is how I interpret the problem.